# Check if external Javascript has been loaded

Tags: javascript

I'm building a system of apps for websites. Many of these apps share code, so to avoid unnecessary redundancy I want to dynamically load the needed code for the apps that need it. My question is, if two apps need the same code, how can I check to see if an app has already loaded the code?

Each app uses a similar line of code:

```
window.addEventListener('load', run_load_functions);
```

to load the needed scripts and do other things (attach event listeners to buttons, load default data, ext.).
I'm sure there is a simple `if` statement I can use in the `run_load_functions`, but I can't think of to how check for scripts.

Comment: Better define what you do mean by `apps`...

Comment: Fire an event on each en every of your specific pieces of code. Better: avoid extra http connections and use something like bower to share code between sites

Comment: I'd recommend using an existing framework one popular framework is require.js see http://requirejs.org/docs/start.html for more information.

Comment: You could try not checking for the scripts themselves and check for what they provide (distinct variable/function/object/class/whatever). if that's missing, then include them.

Comment: I am avoiding the use of premade framework and such. Far as what I mean by 'apps', it's hard to explane, apps may not even the the right work. I guess there like CMS plug-in that can be used without a CMS.

Comment: @notacouch would that work while they/re being added with diffrent onload events? If i set a global variable for it would still be considered 'proper' code?

Comment: Good question. I took a [jQuery plugin and modified it](https://github.com/notacouch/rloader/blob/master/jquery.rloader1_1.js) so it wouldn't have parallel downloads so-to-speak. I just call the script whose resources I need at any time then one of several things happens, 1. if a download hasn't happened yet, download then callback. 2. if a download is happening, wait, then callback, 3. if a download is completed, callback. As for global scope, well it depends. For example `require` or `jQuery` would be global. If a plugin isn't independent of a framework, it probably doesn't belong in global.

Comment: Actually, in regards to global variables again...  since you probably have your own convention going on anyway and if noone else is really going to pick your code up, you could do whatever makes things easier for you.

Comment: would it be better to just load everything even if it may not be needed?

Comment: I can't tell you that. It really depends on if it adversely affects any limitations you may have, particularly on user experience. For example if the sites will only be loaded on an evergreen browser on a desktop within a small company's intranet... then you probably have a lot less to worry about. It's not just the download size of css/js but the overall time it takes to process. Use DevTools timeline features to compare/contrast if loading everything vs loading modularly make a significant difference or not.